# Query to Find "Remaining Bill Amount" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
PaymentID  Date           TotalBill   Bill Paid Amount    Remaining Bill

1          05-04-2018      2,10,000      20,000             1,90,000
2          10-05-2018      2,10,000      60,000             1,30,000
3          13-06-2018      2,10,000      30,000             1,00,000
```

The payment of a Bill is paid in installments in different dates as shown above. How to find the remaining Bill amount each time when the partial payment of bill is made? I wants the above result but i don't know correct SQL Server query.

I used the following Query:

```
SELECT siph.SupplyPaymentID,si.SupplyInvoiceID,siph.DateOfPayment,si.TotalBill,siph.BillPaidAmount,(si.TotalBill-siph.BillPaidAmount) as RemainingBillAmount from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join SupplyInvoice si on siph.SupplyInvoiceID=si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

But it produces the following wrong result

```
PaymentID  Date           TotalBill   Bill Paid Amount    Remaining Bill

    1          05-04-2018      2,10,000      20,000             1,90,000
    2          10-05-2018      2,10,000      60,000             1,50,000
    3          13-06-2018      2,10,000      30,000             1,80,000
```

How to find the correct remaining Bill amount each time when the partial payment of bill is made?

Comment: What year of `SQL-Server`?

Comment: SQL server 2012.. i am new in sql please send me the query to find the correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/XIFRJ98026)**</kbd>

you can try a query like below

```
SELECT 
    siph.SupplyPaymentID,
    si.SupplyInvoiceID,
    siph.DateOfPayment,
    si.TotalBill,
    siph.BillPaidAmount,
    si.TotalBill-SUM(siph.BillPaidAmount) over( order by siph.DateOfPayment asc) as RemainingBillAmount 
from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph 
inner join SupplyInvoice si 
on siph.SupplyInvoiceID=si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUM` function with the `OVER` clause.

```
SELECT siph.SupplyPaymentID, 
si.SupplyInvoiceID, 
siph.DateOfPayment, 
si.TotalBill,
siph.BillPaidAmount, 
SUM(si.TotalBill-siph.BillPaidAmount) OVER(ORDER BY siph.DateOfPayment ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RemainingBillAmount 
FROM SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph 
INNER JOIN SupplyInvoice si ON siph.SupplyInvoiceID = si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

Comment: it produces the following error "Invalid column name 'Date'." if i use the siph.DateOfPayment instead of Date in"OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)"  it produces correct result only in First row.

Comment: if i use the siph.DateOfPayment instead of Date in"OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)" it produces  following result                                                                                           PaymentID  Date           TotalBill   Bill Paid Amount    Remaining Bill

    1          05-04-2018      2,10,000      20,000             1,90,000
    2          10-05-2018      2,10,000      60,000             3,40,000
    3          13-06-2018      2,10,000      30,000             3,40,000

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(PaymentID,[Date],TotalBill,BillPaidAmount)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'05-04-2018',210000,20000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'10-05-2018',210000,60000 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'13-06-2018',210000,30000   
)
SELECT *, TotalBill-SUM(BillPaidAmount)OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS RemainingBill   FROM CTE
```

Result

```
PaymentID   Date        TotalBill   BillPaidAmount  RemainingBill
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1           05-04-2018    210000        20000           190000
2           10-05-2018    210000        60000           130000
3           13-06-2018    210000        30000           100000
```

Demo:http://rextester.com/MKP99723

Comment: please send the query again

Answer (score 0):

if i use the siph.DateOfPayment instead of Date in"OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)" it produces  following result

```
PaymentID  Date           TotalBill   Bill Paid Amount    Remaining Bill

1          05-04-2018      2,10,000      20,000             1,90,000
2          10-05-2018      2,10,000      60,000             3,40,000
3          13-06-2018      2,10,000      30,000             3,40,000
```